# Understanding how recursion works with multiple returns

Tags: recursion

The following problem is from codingbat:Given an array of ints, is it possible to choose a group of some of the ints, such that the group sums to the given target?

The author of the site has provided the following solution:

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0);
  if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) return true;
  if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

---

Suppose I wanted to try the following case where nums=[2,4,8] and called groupSum(0,nums,10).

I see that `groupSum(0,nums,10)` will call `groupSum(1,nums,10)` and `groupSum(1,nums,8)`.

`groupSum(1,nums,10)` calls `groupSum(2, nums,10)` and `groupSum(2, nums,6)`

`groupSum(1,nums,8)` calls `groupSum(2,nums,8)` and `groupSum(1,nums,4)`

etc...

Working through the code I see the following calls:

```
groupSum(3,nums,10)
groupSum(3,nums,2)
groupSum(3,nums,6)
groupSum(3,nums,-2)
groupSum(3,nums,8)
groupSum(3,nums,0)
groupSum(3,nums,4)
groupSum(3,nums,-4)
```

I see that `groupSum(3,nums,0)` should return true because of the first line:
`if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0);` But I'm confused about the other calls like `groupSum(3,nums,-4)`. From the first line it should clearly result in false since `target != 0`.

Also could someone explain why the return true statement is necessary in

```
if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start])) return true;
```

I thought the first line would determine true or false.

```
if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target)) return true;
```

Comment: It's recursion!  Did you expect it to make sense??

Comment: I expect groupSum(3,nums,4) is not being called BY groupSum(3,nums,0), but is being called from another earlier one. You could add a fourth variable to see the callee - add start+'_'+target to every call, and then print that out to see where it came from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically the function can be broken down to this:

1. If "start" (the current position in the array of numbers) is part the end of the array (in other words, if we've tried all the numbers), then the function was successful if the target was reached (ie. is zero)
2. Otherwise, continue iterating (`start+1`) with the current number included (`target-nums[start]`) and if that works return `true`
3. Otherwise, including the current number didn't work, so continue iterating without the current number. If that works, return `true`
4. If we've gotten to this point, then there is no way to add the numbers that works, so return `false`.

You've broken down the steps of all the possible function calls, and as you observed there is one that returns true (the one where target is zero). This `true` result cascades back up the recursion to be the final return value.

Here's a rough breakdown of how it works:

```
groupSum(0,[2,4,8],10)
0 >= 3? no, so continue:
groupSum(1,[2,4,8],10-2)?
  1 >= 3? no, so continue:
  groupSum(2,[2,4,8],8-4)?
    2 >= 3? no, so continue:
    groupSum(3,[2,4,8],4-8)?
      3 >= 3? yes. -4 == 0? no, return false
    groupSum(3,[2,4,8],4)?
      3 >= 3? yes. 4 == 0? no, return false
    return false
  groupSum(2,[2,4,8],8)?
    2 >= 3? no, so continue:
    groupSum(3,[2,4,8],8-8)?
      3 >= 3? yes. 0 == 0? yes, return true
    yes, return true
  yes, return true
yes, return true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks!

Comment: Little confuse :( Please help, How comparing target == 0 will check the group sums to the given target.

Comment: @prdp89 Because each iteration is subtracting the current test value from the target (to get what remains), if that is 0 then it's a match. Because if `a == b` then `a - b == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Kolink's detailed walk through, for what its worth, in Java, I created this to help me see:

```
public class TestRecursion{

    public static boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target, String s) {
        System.out.println(new String(new char[start]).replace("\0", "    ")+"start="+start+" target="+target+" parent="+s);
        if (start >= nums.length) return (target == 0);
        if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target - nums[start], "A:"+start+"_"+target)) return true;
        if (groupSum(start + 1, nums, target, "B:"+start+"_"+target)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        int[] nums = {2,4,8};
        groupSum(0, nums, 10, "");
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
start=0 target=10 parent=
    start=1 target=8 parent=A:0_10
        start=2 target=4 parent=A:1_8
            start=3 target=-4 parent=A:2_4
            start=3 target=4 parent=B:2_4
        start=2 target=8 parent=B:1_8
            start=3 target=0 parent=A:2_8
```

Comment: Your welcome. I also just added indentation generation to the code to make it more clear.